# jquery: find parent sibling attribute value

Tags: jquery

code:

```
<div class="bf3l bf3s">
    <div class="fleft">some text</div>
    <div class="tool_click_lbl" data-container-id="trgt_area_container">select</div>
    <div id="codeid_15txt" class="fleft pad0_10 blue">location</div>
    <div id="trgt_area_container" class="slider_container">
    <div class="slider_closex fright"></div>
    <div class="slider_title fleft">area</div>
    <div class="fixer"></div>
    <ul>
        <li class="xhn_select">some other text</li>
        <li class="xhn_select">some other text</li>
        <li class="xhn_select">some other text</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I click on: **some other text**

I want to find value of attribute: **data-container-id**

I tried (with no success):

```
$(this).closest('tool_click_lbl', 'bf3s').attr('data-container-id');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('.bf3s').find('.tool_click_lbl').data('container-id');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

using `parents()`,`find()`,`data()`

```
$(this).parents('.bf3s').find('.tool_click_lbl').data('container-id');
```

or

using `siblings()`

```
$(this).parents('.slider_container').siblings('.tool_click_lbl').data('container-id');
```

or using `closest()`

```
$(this).closest('.bf3s').find('.tool_click_lbl').data('container-id');
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).parents('.bf3s')...` You're missing your `.` on the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
$(this).parent().prevAll('.tool_click_lbl').attr('data-container-id');
```

But .closest() way seems more accurate here